# iOS - [Class classMethod] results in unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, runtime, unrecognized-selector

Due to code privacy, I have to omit part of info. Just excuse me.

[image]

In `TokenRequestManager.m`, there is an instance method `serialQueue4TokenType`:

```
- (dispatch_queue_t)serialQueue4TokenType:(TokenType)tokenType
{
    static NSMutableDictionary *serialQueueDict = nil;
    if (serialQueueDict == nil) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            serialQueueDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:TokenTypeCount];
        });
    }

    dispatch_queue_t queue;

    @synchronized (self) {
        NSString *key = [TokenManager tokenName4Type:tokenType];
        key = [key stringByAppendingString:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
        NSValue *value = serialQueueDict[key];

        if (value == nil) {
            queue = dispatch_queue_create(key.UTF8String, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
            value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&queue objCType:@encode(dispatch_queue_t)];
            serialQueueDict[key] = value;
        } else {
            [value getValue:&queue];
        }
    }

    return queue;
}
```

Just below the `@synchronized (self) {` line, it calls the Class method:

```
+ (NSString *)tokenName4Type:(TokenType)tokenType
{
    NSString *string = nil;

    switch (tokenType) {
        case TokenTypeBiz:
            return @"TokenTypeBiz";
            break;

        case TokenTypeWeb:
        default:
            string = @"TokenTypeWeb";
            break;
    }

    return string;
}
```

The code just stands there, but sometimes (a few times) the app will crash at this line with `unrecognized selector sent`, no matter debug or release.

Any tips will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would synchronize on  `[self class]` and set tokenName4Type as a regular function, not a method -- i admit i don't know why it locks, though.

Comment: + (NSString *)tokenName4Type:(TokenType *)tokenType

Comment: @CharlesThierry thanks all the same